Dependency injection for constructors that implement the same interface in Go using Fx
I'm trying to use Fx framework for dependency injection in a Go project. I have multiple constructors that return different implementations of the same interface, Observer, and I want to inject them using Fx's group functionality. However, I'm encountering an error about missing types, and I can't seem to properly inject the observers into my controller.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Observer Interface
// Observer interface
type Observer interface {
    Update(ctx context.Context, eventName string, eventData []EventData) error
}

// First Observer Implementation 
func NewObserverA(logger *Logger, repo Repository, env EnvContext) (Observer, error) {
    return &ObserverA{
        logger:     logger,
        repo:       repo,
        envContext: env,
    }, nil
}

// Second Observer Implementation 
func NewObserverB(logger *Logger, repo Repository, producer MessageGateway, env EnvContext) (Observer, error) {
    return &ObserverB{
        logger:        logger,
        repo:          repo,
        producer:      producer,
        envContext:    env,
    }, nil
}

Module Setup
var Module = fx.Options(
    fx.Provide(NewObserverA),
    fx.Provide(NewObserverB),
    fx.Provide(
        fx.Annotate(NewObserverA, fx.ResultTags(`group:"observers"`)),
        fx.Annotate(NewObserverB, fx.ResultTags(`group:"observers"`)),
    ),
)

Controller Setup
// Controller interface
type Controller interface {
    // Methods...
}

type controller struct {
    logger      *Logger
    repo        Repository
    observers   []Observer  // Injected slice of observers
    someService Service
}

func NewController(
    logger *Logger,
    repo Repository,
    observers []Observer,  // This matches the injected group
    service Service,
) (Controller, error) {
    return &controller{
        logger:     logger,
        repo:       repo,
        observers:  observers,  // Injected observers
        someService: service,
    }, nil
}

Error
missing type:
    - []workflow.Observer (did you mean to Provide it?)


There are instructions for consuming a value group at https://uber-go.github.io/fx/value-groups/consume.html. You don't seem to be doing any of the things that that page says to do, so I'm guessing that you just haven't seen it?

Thank you! I have not seen that page before. I was able to resolve the issue by adding the following code to the controller module,  so that the  value group was consumed properly using annotated function:  fx.Provide(fx.Annotate(NewController, fx.ParamTags("", "", group:"observers", "")))

Very nice! My pleasure. :-)

As mentioned by @ruakh, you'll need to use annotations to consume a value group.
You should be Go idiomatic and return concrete types from your constructors and decouple registration by “casting structs to interfaces.”
As a more complete example from “register many handlers”, define your constructors as:
func NewObserverA(logger *Logger, repo Repository, env EnvContext) (*ObserverA, error) {
    return &ObserverA{
        logger:     logger,
        repo:       repo,
        envContext: env,
    }, nil
}

func NewObserverB(logger *Logger, repo Repository, producer MessageGateway, env EnvContext) (*ObserverB, error) {
    return &ObserverB{
        logger:     logger,
        repo:       repo,
        producer:   producer,
        envContext: env,
    }, nil
}

then define a function AsObserver to feed into the observers group:
func AsObserver(f any) any {
    return fx.Annotate(
        f,
        fx.As(new(Observer), new(error)),
        fx.ResultTags(`group:"observers"`),
    )
}

and wrap your constructors like:
var Module = fx.Options(
    fx.Provide(
        AsObserver(NewObserverA),
        AsObserver(NewObserverB),
    ),
)

You can then feed that into your controller with:
func NewController(
    logger *Logger,
    repo Repository,
    observers []Observer,
    service Service,
) (*controller, error) {
    return &controller{
        logger:      logger,
        repo:        repo,
        observers:   observers,
        someService: service,
    }, nil
}

var Module = fx.Options(
    fx.Provide(
        fx.Annotate(
            NewController,
            fx.As(new(Controller), new(error)),
            fx.ParamTags("", "", `group:"observers"`, "")),
    ),
)

returning a concrete type again.

From https://uber-go.github.io/fx/get-started/http-server.html:

We used fx.Provide to add an HTTP server to the application. The server hooks into the Fx application lifecycle--it will start serving requests when we call App.Run, and it will stop running when the application receives a stop signal. We used fx.Invoke to request that the HTTP server is always instantiated, even if none of the other components in the application reference it directly.

Maybe you need run fx.Invoke once?
